# Pay for a Doctorate by working at institution?

Tags: tuition

A friend of mine was working on a doctorate at a local university, and they offered to hire him as an adjunct so he wouldn't have to pay for the doctorate.  Is there an easier way for me to search which universities might offer this opportunity besides Google?

Comment: Were are you from? In Germany this is kind of "standard procedure". So nearly every PhD student is financed by having a job at the university. Some have a stipend but thats more of an exception while working at the university is standard. So at least for Germany I would say this is offered/possible everywhere.

Comment: It's a bit more uncommon to be hired as an adjunct, but in the US nearly all PhDs are paid for all or in part by graduate assistantships of some kind. In STEM research assistantships predominate, in other fields there are more teaching assistantships. Typically if you work a high enough % of your time, tuition is covered (this is called "tuition remission"). I would strongly advise against any PhD that you have to pay for out of pocket.

Comment: Must universities in the US I've seen allow full-time employees and some part-time employees to take X number of hours for free, often termed as a *tuition waiver*. That how I did my PhD actually. I don't think there's a centralized list of universities based on provided employee benefits though.